# pyserial isOpen() always returning True

Tags: python, pyserial

i am observing a problem with pyserial module, if i do the below pyhton program to open the serial port, the function ser.isOpen() always return true even if i had opened the PORT in minicom . Do anyone have any idea about this, how to return False if the serial port is already open ?

if i give wrong serial port name, it throws error in the init.

```
import serial

PORT="/dev/ttyUSB0"
BAUD=115200

ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD)
if(ser.isOpen() == True):
        print(ser.name + " is open ...");
else:
    print("not able to open serial port: " + PORT)
```